# What approach should I take to implement Authorization in Lambda (Triggers) without using the AppSync for a specific module of my project?

Tags: aws-lambda, authorization, aws-amplify, serverless, aws-appsync

I currently utilize Amplify in conjunction with AppSync and Cognito for authentication in my project. The backend APIs handle the interaction with the DynamoDB database. However, I now face a limitation as I wish to directly interact with the database, bypassing the additional API call. This presents a challenge as Amplify handles all the authorization. I am seeking an optimized solution to address this issue. Could you please provide guidance on how to approach this in detail?

I am currently implementing the solution that I will call the AppSync API at the start of the flow. I am assuming that the rest of the flow will work fine. But, even if it works, it utilizes the API call again. I want to reduce the API calling for an optimized solution.

Comment: So is [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/#graphql-from-lambda) not what you're looking for?

Comment: No. @John Actually, the user can get the query from the network tab, and that causes the security breach. So, I need to handle that specific scenario.